# Heroku SSL endpoint - do I need to change the git remote?

Tags: git, ssl, heroku

I've set up a SSL endpoint for a heroku app - all the certificate magic seems to have gone fine - just waiting for DNS to propogate

My question is do I need to update my git remote ?

Right now I'm pointing to .herokuapp.com and my ssl endpoint is .herokussl.com

So do I need to point the git remote to the herokussl address - or is the herokussl.com simply a sort of proxy and my app and database remain untouched ?

I don't think I need to do anything but if someone has a definitive answer that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your Heroku Git remote stays the same after you add SSL.